# Fetch more than 100 records on MongoDB with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm using the new [MongoDB PHP driver](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongodb.php). I've been searching how I can get more than 100 records from a query.

I'm using [`executeCommand`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.executecommand.php) to pass the query. I think that in the old driver, the [`cursor`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-cursor.php) object had a `getNext` method to get other pages, but It does not have anymore. How can I get the other "pages" from my query?

Comment: How many records are you getting using `executeCommand` ?

Comment: I'm getting 100 records (100 documents). 180 is the total.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [MongoDB\Driver\Query](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.executequery.php) and [MongoDB\Driver\Manager::executeQuery](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-server.executequery.php) methods.

Here's a short sample for demonstration:

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');
$query   = new MongoDB\Driver\Query([], []);
$cursor  = $manager->executeQuery('DB.Collection', $query);
$array   = $cursor->toArray();
```

Note that resulting `$array` contains documents (records) as instances of `stdClass Object`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution and it returns all the documents in collection.

```
<?php
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(array('find' => "testColl"));
$cursor = $manager->executeCommand('testDb', $command);

print_r($cursor->toArray());
?>
```